# query and update time based actions

Tags: soql, metadata-api, tooling-api, time-dependent-workflow

I have a requirement to update the time trigger condition in a active time based workflow rule

Right now there are more than 1000 records related to it as i can see in the monitoring secttion, but i can't see more than 1000 records, to see those records i need to delete current scheduled actions

is there any object availaible to query via tooling/ metadata api or any way through which i can query the scheduled actions

right now i can see following ideas in salesforce

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TptlQAC

ideas says that it is not possible right now, let me know if this is not possible at all

if not possible, then last resort for me would be to query the records on the basis of workflow condition and then trigger them again

Answer (score 0):

I think your last resort would be my first approach to try:

1. Update workflow criteria
2. Update all records matching the original criteria (just to trigger recalculation).
3. See what happens to the time-based actions in the queue.